# How to get a PageReference from Site.login(username, password, url) in an Apex Test

Tags: apex, unit-test, lightning-web-components, force.com-sites, pagereference

When I run this code from within a LWC controller:

```
ApexPages.PageReference pageRef = Site.login(username, password, url);
```

It returns a valid `PageReference` instance.

But when I test the code in a `Apex Test` class, the variable `pageRef` is always `null`

Here is my controller Apex class:

```
public classs CustomerSignupController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String createAccount(SignupParams params) {

        // create user, account and portal user etc

        ApexPages.PageReference pageRef = Site.login(email, password, null);

        if (pageRef == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return pageRef.getUrl();
    }        
}
```

Here is my Apex test code:

```
// arrange
String response;
Test.setCurrentPage(new PageReference('/customer/s/signup'));

// act
Test.startTest();
System.runAs(u) {
    response = CustomerSignupController.createAccount(params);
}
Test.stopTest();

// assert
System.assertNotEquals(null, response);
```

I am running the code within the `User` context of the `Portal Site Guest User`

And, I've tried setting `Test.setCurrentPage` but it does not make any difference, but perhaps I am not creating the `PageReference` correctly?

NOTE: please do **not** provide solutions that involve polluting my production code with:

```
if (Test.isRunningTest()) { ... }
```

I'd to like to understand how I can use `Test.setCurrentPage` when testing an LWC component's apex controller to work around the issue and test the code correctly.

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I make `Site.login` return a valid `PageReference` from within a test?

Comment: Can you see the json value of pagereference and set the same JSON(kind of mocking part). So that assertion will be proper. You can make this pagereference as testvisible so that you can test both ways, null and valid way.

Comment: @YsrShk - do you have an example of this approach?

Comment: for site.login no. I typically use JSON to set the object. Like we used to set the pastdated createdDate by using JSON.